# Why aren't my DIV's responding to row and columns break points?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I'm creating a row of highlighted products on my website. On desktop view I have 5 products. When I get to a medium size device, I want there to be 2 products and finally on mobile, 1 product. After reading Bootstrap's documentation on [Grid System and Rows here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns) I added the `row-cols` syntax and nothing happens. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't figure out what it is. Also, in the codepen project I'm showing here, the product's info (image and text) get squeezed.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/QWboYmN) my CodePen.

This is what it looks like in my computer, desktop view (it looks fine)

[image: This is what it looks like in my computer, desktop view (it looks fine)]

This is what it looks like in my computer when I make the screen size smaller. Not good.

[image: This is what it looks like in my computer when I make the screen size smaller. Not good.]

Comment: do you link bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes to this version and u will have ur grid. And make sure u will use Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">this</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">is</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">example</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">use</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">this</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment above did it:

Try this. Make two bootstrap layouts of these products in two different sections. One for larger screens and one for smaller screens. (For the smaller screens u can define 3 rows or 2 rows depending on your preference) But keep the small screen layout invisible. Add a media query to your CSS which will make the larger screen layout invisible and make the small screen layout visible upon reaching the breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is define breakpoints using media queries. This way you can define how many rows should be there and how the columns should be spanned out depending on how small the screen is.

Comment: The documentation in Bootstrap says that this can be achieved my using this structure:
`<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>`

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try this. Make two bootstrap layouts of these products in two different sections. One for larger screens and one for smaller screens. (For the smaller screens u can define 3 rows or 2 rows depending on your preference) But keep the small screen layout invisible. Add a media query to your CSS which will make the larger screen layout invisible and make the small screen layout visible upon reaching the breakpoint.